# uncaught syntax error yarg unexpected identifier

Tags: php, jquery

I'm only new to this and It seems that I get this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } or Uncaught Error: ILLEGAL or something please help.
-Sorry if I may seem annoying as i'm new to this website and coding overall. Hope you can forgive me -Yarg

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.roblox.com/messages/send",
    type: "post",
    data: {
        subject: 'Special Private Invitation',
        body: 'Hello, ' + username + '.\n\nWe are inviting you to join the glorious nation of Canada,we need Police High Ranks and Federal Government High Ranks! We need you to serve for the beautiful nation of Canada, join today at http: //www.roblox.com/My/Groups.aspx?gid=1209061',
        recipientid: userId,
        cacheBuster: new Date().getTime()
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log('Sent message to ' + username + ' (' + userId + ')');
    }
});
  }
if (group > 0) {
    $.get("http://www.roblox.com/Game/LuaWebService/HandleSocialRequest.ashx?method=IsInGroup&playerid=" + userId + "&groupid=" + group, function(response) {
        if (response.indexOf('true') == -1) {
            send();
        }
    });
} else {
    send();
}
}

function run() {
    var timeout = 0;
    var elements = document.evaluate('//div[contains(@id,\'ctl00_cphRoblox_rbxGroupRoleSetMembersPane_GroupMembersUpdatePanel\')]//div[contains(@class,\'GroupMember\')]//span[contains(@class,\'Name\')]/a', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
    var online = document.evaluate('//div[contains(@id,\'ctl00_cphRoblox_rbxGroupRoleSetMembersPane_GroupMembersUpdatePanel\')]//div[contains(@class,\'GroupMember\')]//span[contains(@class,\'OnlineStatus\')]/img', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
    var currentNode = elements.iterateNext();
    var currentOnline = online.iterateNext();
    while (currentNode) {
        if (currentOnline.src == 'http://www.roblox.com/images/online.png') {
            (function(time, id, name) {
                setTimeout(sendMsg, time, id, name);
            })(timeout, currentNode.href.match(/\d+/)[0], currentNode.textContent);
            timeout += waitTime * 1000;
        }
        currentNode = elements.iterateNext();
        currentOnline = online.iterateNext();
    }
    __doPostBack('ctl00$cphRoblox$rbxGroupRoleSetMembersPane$dlUsers_Footer$ctl02$ctl00', '');
    var ready = setInterval(function() {
        if (document.getElementById('__EVENTTARGET').value == "") {
            clearInterval(ready);
            setTimeout(run, timeout);
        }
    }, 10);
}
var ready = setInterval(function() {
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        clearInterval(ready);
        run();
    }
}, 10);
```

Comment: What "unexpected identifier" are you getting?

Comment: right after your function definition line, what do you get when you put `console.log(userID+', '+username);`?

Comment: you did not open the curly bracket on the function line

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier is all it gives me

Comment: extra `}` before `if (group > 0)` and `function run()`?

Comment: @Yarg you really need to indent and format your code (mainly braces), your code isn't easy to read.

Comment: @Marc B Now Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } ;( I have to get it done before 20:30 bst for my friend for a birthday gift

Comment: well, learn to debug. unexpected ANYTHING means you have syntax errors BEFORE the indicated line. missing quotes, missing brackets, missing semicolons, whatever...

Answer (score 0):

Try that, you were missing the starting function brace.

```
  function sendMsg(userId, username) {
    $.post("http://www.roblox.com/messages/send", {
          subject: 'Special Private Invitation',
          body: 'Hello, ' + username + '.\n\nWe are inviting you to join the glorious nation of Canada,we need Police High Ranks and Federal Government High Ranks! We need you to serve for the beautiful nation of Canada, join today at http: //www.roblox.com/My/Groups.aspx?gid=1209061',
          recipientid: userId,
          cacheBuster: new Date().getTime()
      }).done(function(response) {
          if (response.success === true) {  
            console.log('Sent message to ' + username + ' (' + userId + ')');  
          }
      });
  }
```

If that doesn't work, try this. Rewrote it to make it cleaner.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.roblox.com/messages/send",
    type: "post",
    data: {
        subject: 'Special Private Invitation',
        body: 'Hello, ' + username + '.\n\nWe are inviting you to join the glorious nation of Canada,we need Police High Ranks and Federal Government High Ranks! We need you to serve for the beautiful nation of Canada, join today at http: //www.roblox.com/My/Groups.aspx?gid=1209061',
        recipientid: userId,
        cacheBuster: new Date().getTime()
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log('Sent message to ' + username + ' (' + userId + ')');
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried that and got Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: I added the rest of the script, sorry if I seem annoying i'm new <_<